# How do I query a custom post type with a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I need to grab any posts using a custom taxonomy.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'adverts',
    'advert_tag' => 'politics' // Doesn't seem to work.
);

query_posts($args); 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    //Show Posts
endwhile;
```

Taxonomy Declaration:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomy', 0 );
function add_custom_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy('advert_tag', 'Adverts', 
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Advert Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Advert Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Advert Tags' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Advert Tags' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Advert Tag' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Advert Tag:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Advert Tag' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Advert Tag' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Advert Tag' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Advert Tag Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Advert Tags' ),
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'advert-tags',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
    );
}
```

Custom Post Type Declaration:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'Adverts',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Adverts' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Advert'),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add a New Advert' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Advert' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Advert' ),
                'view' => __( 'View' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Advert' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Adverts' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No Adverts found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Adverts found in Trash' ),
            ),
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'thumbnail',
            ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_position' => 10,
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 
                'slug' => 'adverts' 
            ),
            'taxonomies' => array('advert_tag')
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Firs of all **don't use `query_posts()` ever**, read more about it here: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

You have to use `WP_Query` to fetch posts what you need. Read [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for it. In your case the query could be like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'Adverts',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'advert_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'politics',
        )
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    // Show Posts ...
endwhile;

/* Restore original Post Data 
 * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
 * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset.
*/
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Just noticed that it seems to pull all posts with the custom post type 'Adverts'. However this seems to do the job:

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'Adverts',
        'advert_tag' => 'politics'
));

Comment: @Stephen {tax} was deprecated since version 3.1 in favor of {tax_query} and {tax_query} was introduced. this still works but we should not use the deprecated functions.

tax_query is used with an array of taxonomy queries. i was working on FAQs Custom Post type and it worked for me pretty much the same way as {tax} taxonomy slug argument in WP_Query does.

Answer (score 24):

i am using this query to fetch custom posts (FAQs Posts) with its custom taxonomy (faq_category). since {taxonomy} parameter in WP_Query args was deprecated since v.3.1 and introduced {tax_query}. below is the code that works perfectly.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'faqs',          // name of post type.
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'faq_category',   // taxonomy name
            'field' => 'term_id',           // term_id, slug or name
            'terms' => 48,                  // term id, term slug or term name
        )
    )
) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    // do stuff here....
endwhile;

/**
 * reset the orignal query
 * we should use this to reset wp_query
 */
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - the accepted answer will not filter by taxonomy since the tax_query requires an array of arrays. This nested method is essential to getting this to work. Thanks for your answer )

Comment: yes you are right, welcome Tom Dyer

Comment: Yes, this one also helped me to get the taxonomies template to work. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @AamerShahzad I have the exact same question and I used your answer but the page is pulling no posts. Can you help me out here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783769/how-do-i-pull-only-one-category-from-custom-post-type-in-a-template

Answer (score 2):

Here the code that works like magic. I am fetching all posts for the custom post_type "university_unit" with custom taxonomy "unit_type" and multiple taxonomy terms as "directorate" and "office".
I hope it helps out.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'university_unit',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(

        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'unit_type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('directorate', 'office')
        )

    )
);

$Query = new WP_Query($args);
if($Query -> have_posts()):

    while($Query -> have_posts()):
        $Query -> the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="cm-post-list-item">
            <article>
                <div class="cm-post-head">
                    <h3 class="cm-text-blue">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="cm-post-body"><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;

else:
    "No Administrative Offices Found. Try again later";
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This helped me to get all posts listed under each term for custom taxanomy for CPT

```
    <?php
    // Get list of all taxonomy terms  -- In simple categories title
    $args = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order'   => 'ASC'
            );
    $cats = get_categories($args);

    // For every Terms of custom taxonomy get their posts by term_id
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>">
            <?php echo $cat->name; ?> <br>
            <?php // echo $cat->term_id; ?> <br>
        </a>


            <?php
                // Query Arguments
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'portfolio', // the post type
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'project_category', // the custom vocabulary
                            'field'    => 'term_id',          // term_id, slug or name  (Define by what you want to search the below term)    
                            'terms'    => $cat->term_id,      // provide the term slugs
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                // The query
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                // The Loop
                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    echo '<h2> List of posts tagged with this tag </h2>';

                    echo '<ul>';
                    $html_list_items = '';
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        $html_list_items .= '<li>';
                        $html_list_items .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                        $html_list_items .= get_the_title();
                        $html_list_items .= '</a>';
                        $html_list_items .= '</li>';
                    }
                    echo $html_list_items;
                    echo '</ul>';

                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }

                wp_reset_postdata(); // reset global $post;

                ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer now is not valid anymore since wordpress changes their taxonomy parameter information. please use this way. It will work. It works for me. "tax_query" replaces with "tax". hope it will work.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'Adverts',
    'tax' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'advert_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'politics',
        )
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    // Show Posts ...
endwhile;

/* Restore original Post Data 
 * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
 * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset.
*/
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: It's the exact opposite - `tax` was the old way, `tax_query` is the current (v3.1+) way.

Comment: Well I am working v4.5 and it works with me

Comment: WP is famous for being backwards-compatible. The old way still works, but it's been deprecated, so it may eventually be removed and it's safer to use the newer method.

Comment: Yes now changed from tax to tay_query..