# Get only one custom post from each category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have create custom post(book). In which i have five texonomy categories: CatA, CatB, CatC, CatD, CatE. & i want to show only 3 posts and i want that these posts coming from CatA, CatC, CatD.(One post each these categories.)

```
<?php

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'book',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categories',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => array('CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC')
            ))
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>
                <div style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(''`enter code here`);?>')">
                </div>

                <?php the_title();?>

            <?php } // end while ?>

        <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please also post a sample of the results of this query?

Comment: You will need to loop through the categories and separately query one post from each.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a [taxonomy query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) rather than the `terms` field (I don't see `terms` as a valid parameter on [WordPress's WP_Query documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)). This [stackexchange question and answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/how-do-i-query-a-custom-post-type-with-a-custom-taxonomy) should provide you with the necessary code to do what you are trying to do.

If, however, the categories are *not* custom taxonomies (or really are just categories), then you might be able to [use one of the approaches here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters).

Answer (score -1):

Please Try below code to get only one custom post from each terms. replace terms ids with your term ids in `$array_term = array(16,21);`

```
    # pass your term IDS
    $array_term = array(16,21); 
    $terms_array = array( 
      'taxonomy' => 'categories',// you can change it according to your taxonomy
      'include' => $array_term,
      'parent'   => 0 // If parent => 0 is passed, only top-level terms will be returned
    );

    $categories_terms = get_terms($terms_array); 
    foreach($categories_terms as $categorie_term): ?>
        <h4><?php echo $categorie_term->name; ?></h4>
        <?php 
        $post_args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => 1,
              'post_type' => 'book', // you can change it according to your custom post type
              'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'categories', // you can change it according to your taxonomy
                      'field' => 'term_id', // this can be 'term_id', 'slug' & 'name'
                      'terms' => $categorie_term->term_id,
                  )
              )
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($post_args); 
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) 
            {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) 
                {
                    $query->the_post(); 
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                     </li>
                    <?php
                }
           }
         wp_reset_postdata(); 
    endforeach; // End Term foreach;
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Why are you going through all the effort of getting the terms with get_terms when you already have the IDs?

Comment: i have gave just an idea how to achieve    his need, i have displayed terms name using get_terms. i know that i have  terms ids. i have used get_terms just for reference.