# Archive page for taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

How can I create a archive over terms from a custom taxonomy like there is for custom post types? `domain.com/taxonomy` is empty/404, while `domain.com/cpt` shows all posts for that CPT.

I know I could loop true all terms and display them on a "static" page that I make myself and apply with the template `page-taxonomy.php`. This does however not allow me to have a "Next page" function as far as I know.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'taxonomy' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name
}
```

Is there a way to make a "normal" archive for the terms of a taxonomy? I do not want the posts of the terms/taxonomy, but the terms themself.

Comment: You need to look into https://wphierarchy.com/. Taxonomy template for cpt requires a certain naming of the template file according to the wp template hierarchy. Also, look at my answer in this question. It is very detailed and shows a tax template file hierarchy. Look at step 3 in that post. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378422/custom-post-type-category-taxonomy-and-url-rewrite-problem/378478#378478

Comment: @user3135691 thanks for the reply, but I don't want a archive for CPT but for the taxonomy terms themselves. There is no built-in function for that in WordPress.

Comment: You didn't read correctly, I said Step 3, that is exactly what you need, but hey, no read no progress.

Comment: @user3135691 I have tried to reread what you have written, but I still fail to see how it solves my problem. Your answer is to show posts on /taxonomy, and I want to show terms on /taxonomy. Maybe you would try to expand upon it in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make a "normal" archive for the terms of a taxonomy?

No, there isn't.

All WordPress views are queries for a post or a collection of posts. There's zero built in functionality for an archive of terms, so you would need to implement it yourself (including pagination).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am aware that this is not built into WordPress. What I am asking for is suggestions to how this could be accomplished.