# Featured Category or Special Category in WordPress

Tags: categories, labels

Is there a way to make a category that will show in all categories in WordPress?

For example, categories on my website are:

- Cat A
- Cat B

  - Cat B1
  - Cat B2
  - Cat B3

I want a post tagged in Category A to be shown also in Category B and its children. So when they check mywebsite.com/category/cat-b1 they will also find Cat A.

I do not really know how to code, but I always can follow steps.

Comment: Without a plugin... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) filter, which allows you to change they query before it is executed. In this way you can add Cat A to any request for categories. Like this:

```
add_filter ('pre_get_posts', 'wpse380282_add_cat_a');
function wpse380282_add_cat_a ($query) {
  // do this only on the front end for the main query if it is a category archive
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_category() ) {
    // get the ID for Cat A
    $cat_id = get_cat_ID ('Cat A');
    // get category of the query (returns an array of current categories)
    $cats = $query->get( 'cat' );
    // add Cat A to the array of current categories
    $cats[] = $cat_id;
    // set the category query to the expanded array
    $query->set( 'cat', $cats );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @cjbj, thanks alot for your answer. Is it possible to do it for Taxonomy Category? Could you help me how to do it?

Comment: Of course, that's possible. You would have to test for `is_tax` in stead of `is_category` and then `get_the_terms` in stead of `get_cat_ID`. This post may help you further: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/how-do-i-query-a-custom-post-type-with-a-custom-taxonomy

Comment: Hi @cbcj, I tried it and it does not work :/