# Not recognizing my custom templates in hierarchy

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomies to work like category called projects to be used for the attachments.

I want to be able to create the archive page without having to use the CMS.

Currently the only thing I can figure out is to manually create the projects CMS page and attach the custom template there.

Here is my code for the projects taxonomy ( I edited out labels array to keep it simple):

```
register_taxonomy(
    'projects',
    'attachment',
    array(
      'labels' =>  array(
        'name'              => 'Projects',
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'sort' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects', 'with_front' => false)

    )
  );
```

To be clear all of the custom taxonomy seems to be working fine, I wanted to share that code mainly to show the rewrite line.

I thought at this point using [the template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) I would just need to create a file like
`taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`

So I created my file taxonomy-projects.php but if I go to mysite.com/projects it is 404.

I have flushed permalinks multiple times and the way those are set are as custom structure:

`/%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: all pages in WordPress have post queries, if you went to `/projects` and it worked, what would you be expecting to see?

Comment: anything... even just a hello world from the template but it does not recognize the taxonomy-projects template and skips to index.php (currently my theme does not have a 404.php or I assume it would render that)  The problem is not the content of the page, I have that working fine. It is just I can not get that page to render unless I manually create it in CMS and attach template there.  Hopefully I am being clear enough...

Comment: Maybe i am wrong but is that should not be a `taxonomy-attachment-projects.php`?

Comment: @X9DESIGN thanks for the response, I tried and that is also 404

Comment: @zac when you said "it is 404", is it an actual 404 not found error (i.e. the HTTP status is 404), or was it actually just a "no posts found" page?

Comment: @SallyCJ it is actual 404, I noticed at first it was falling back to the index.php then I created a 404.php and now it renders that.

Comment: What theme are you using? Have you tried deactivating all plugins for a while and also clearing your caches? Did the same 404 issue persist?

Comment: It is a theme I am building, I am fine with template files attached with cms but the template hierarchy does not seem to recognize my custom taxonomy,, maybe because they are for attachments and not posts.

Comment: My expectation is that if you visit `yoursite.com/taxonomy/` without specifying a term, then you would get no results as there is no such thing as a term taxonomy. What I suspect is that you've created a page named `taxonomy` to sit at that location and not shared that information because it seems to obvious to you. If so, then you have a page, not a taxonomy archive, and expecting `taxonomy` templates to show on that page would be weird because pages do not use taxonomy templates, they use page related templates

Comment: @zac Sorry, I kept thinking that a *term* archive (e.g. at `mysite.com/projects/<term slug>`) was showing the 404 page and yet, you're actually referring to a *taxonomy* archive (`mysite.com/projects`) ‍♀️ So as you already know, that doesn't exist in WordPress core, but it can be created manually, e.g. using a static Page (post type `page` and with the slug `projects`) or by creating custom rewrite rules for that URL. Nonetheless, happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register a taxonomy named `projects`, and create `taxonomy-projects.php`, the URL `mysite.com/projects` will not exist. There is no such page in WordPress.

If you create a term inside inside that taxonomy, "My Project", that term will be accessible at `mysite.com/projects/my-project` and that URL will use `taxonomy-projects.php` to list all posts that belong to that project. `mysite.com/projects` on its own does not exist.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks then I am understanding that the only way for me to have this root archive page for my custom taxonomy is manually creating the CMS page and attaching the template with the tax query there?

Comment: That’s correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set public to true? As I can remember without it you can't use your taxonomy in your theme.

```
public bool
Whether a taxonomy is intended for use publicly either via the admin interface or by front-end users. The default settings of $publicly_queryable, $show_ui, and $show_in_nav_menus are inherited from $public.
publicly_queryable bool
Whether the taxonomy is publicly queryable.
If not set, the default is inherited from $public
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with attempting that (adding `'public' => true`,) it did not seem to help, that page is still 404.

Comment: Taxonomy should be attachment to post type. Did you do this?

Comment: No I am using it specifically for the attachments.  I would do a custom post type but I do not know how I could duplicate the attachment functionality there, I do not want post.

Comment: So, you should check your file name is not wrong it is equal taxonomy, URL and etc. May be some letters changed seats.

Comment: If you used custom post type you should make according WP_Query. Look at that https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/how-do-i-query-a-custom-post-type-with-a-custom-taxonomy

Comment: I am having no problem with the query or building the content.  The issue is that the template is being ignored.  My understanding is the existence of that taxonomy slug should just make that php file render what ever it has in it.,  Everything works for me if I build  out the page with CMS and attach template that way.

Comment: What will happen if you change your PHP-file to archive.php

Comment: Yes archive is still ignored and it is 404

Comment: Looks like your taxonomy actually is not one. What if attachment change to post for example?

Comment: Did you set binding between your taxonomy term and attachments which you want to see? I say now about the directly binding via checkbox in the admin panel, not the registry_taxonomy() function.